# Add in copyfeatures into script

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, copy

I am having trouble with CopyFeatures in my script. The files went being copied to the output folder. Can someone please assist. Here's a snippet of my script for ArcGIS 10.3;

```
#Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject
for fc in fcList:
fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
if fcspatialRef != spatialRef==True:
    arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
else:
    fcspatialRef != spatialRef==False:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outFolder) 

# Print shapefile Project results
        arcpy.AddMessage(fc)

# Return any errors   
except:
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Comment: Your indentation for the try/except block is incorrect; is that how your code is written, or just how it's formatted in your post? Also, what error are you getting. And never seen the way you're checking the spatial reference; no idea why you'd have the == True or False, but maybe that does something I don't know.

Comment: Could you please post any errors?

Comment: Please be aware that what you are asking here is really more than fits our focussed Q&A format: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/what-to-do-about-whats-wrong-with-my-wall-of-text-type-questions  As much as possible we need you to think about the **part** of your code which is not working and then present that to us as a code snippet.

Comment: @PolyGeo, sorry that's how I have written the code.

Comment: Your learning experience will be much deeper if you can dissect your code to present just the part (i.e. a code snippet) that represents where you are stuck.  GIS SE is intended to be a focussed Q&A site, and not a code writing/debugging service.  In its current state I think your question is too broad.  I recommend that you absorb the details presented in both answers and accept one or other of them.  If you are still stuck then start a new question with just a code snippet that demonstrates where (with any error message that results).

Comment: For what you have currently to be a working snippet you should probably set `fcList` to some test values first e.g. `fcList = ["abc.shp","xyz.shp"]` and then remove the `except` block - it may be needed in your final code but in this code snippet it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 issues in your code:

1. indentation under the for fc block as @recurvata says
2. useless line after the else
3. output not valid for the CopyFeatures tool.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject
for fc in fcList:
 fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
 if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
  arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
 else:
  arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc) 
  # Print shapefile Project results
  arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
```

Comment: yeah, good catch on the CopyFeatures output

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're kind of "over-checking" for matching spatial references, and you're if/else is a little off.  Try this:

```
# Get the spatial reference
spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference.name 

#Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject
for fc in fcList:
    fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name

    # the expression below will either equal True or False, and that's what
    # the if statement will operate on
    if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
        arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)

    # all cases where the above expression is False will go directly to the
    # else block below
    else:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outFolder)
```

Also, as @recurvata mentioned, the indentation in the code you've posted so far is incorrect, so be careful of that.  For your code:

```
## 1st indentation for try/except blocks
## all code up to...
try:
    ## 2nd indentation for code inside the try/except blocks
    ## some "try" code
    if expression:
        ## 3rd indentation inside of if/else blocks
        ## some "if" code
    else:
        ## some "else" code

## back to 1st indentation for except block
except:
    ## some "except" code
```

hope that helps!